# Is it possible to force ReSharper to implement ICloneable interface?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, icloneable

Is there a possibility to use ReSharper 6.1 to to make my class implement `ICloneable` interface for me?

How?

Comment: Do you mean that you want resharper to generate the code inside the `Clone` method, instead of just a `throw NotImplementedException()`?

Comment: Yes, exactly! This is what I want Resharper to generate, if possible.

Comment: I would be surprised if it had this feature. `ICloneable` use is discouraged. The best (although still slim) chance I can think of is if someone wrote a plugin that does this. Perhaps try searching for that.

Comment: @PaulPhillips Why is the use of `ICloneable` discouraged?

Comment: Use of `ICloneable` is discouraged because it does not specify whether `Clone()` is deep or shallow copy, creating an ambiguity for the end user of the API.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk So, what is the encouraged alternative?

Comment: @Ken do not implement `ICloneable` but instead create your own `IDeepCopyable` interface with member `DeepCopy()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such a feature in `Resharper`. Not yet. Closest thing of what you want is [Extract Interface](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/extractinterface.html) option. Which it adds a new interface not existing one.

Comment: I use excel to generate field=other.field;
HTH